# Reusing old service wires from electric furnace to mini-split

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, subpanel, mini-split

EDIT to answer replies:

@3phaseeel 30-amp wires are 6 AWG aluminum, 50-amp wires are 4 AWG aluminum. The sheathed wires run along the garage roof truss overhead (see picture), exposed for about 28 feet in length, then in-between insulated joists and down a wall, then exposed again in the enclosed crawlspace. I added a picture of the panel door, not sure if the sticker from 1982 adds valuable details.

@manassehkatz Subpanel will be used for dedicated circuits to bathroom heaters, not for heavy-duty usage like welding.

Original question:

I have an unused electric furnace that is serviced by one 30-amp double pole breaker and two 50-amp single pole breakers. I'm thinking of:

(1) reusing the existing wires from the 30-amp circuit to service a new heat pump with a dedicated 25-amp replacement double-pole breaker

(2) reusing the wires from the two 50-amp circuit to service a 100-amp subpanel to serve future wiring projects

Does that sound like a reasonable plan? Or is this plan not as simple as it seems?

Background:

We switched to using a mini-split heat pump two years ago, which cut our electric bill in half, even when used in combination with a few space heaters. Having had good experience with the mini-split, I now want to install another unit to completely replace the space heaters and retire the unused, noisy, leaky, 38-year old furnace. I am a DIY homeowner with advanced beginner to intermediate level of know-how and tools.

[image: furnace circuit breakers]

[image: wiring along garage overhead]

[image: panel door stickers]

[image: whole panel covered]

[image: panel uncovered]

[image: 50-amp cable label]

[image: left inside panel]

[image: right inside panel]

[image: right label, inside panel]

Comment: What size *are* the wires going to the 50A breakers, and what sort of cable or conduit are they run in? Also, where were you planning on putting the new subpanel, and can you post a photo of the labeling on the inside of your breaker box's door please?

Comment: When you say "100A subpanel" is that "I want to put in a 100A panel because they're nice and big, but I will only have a few circuits in and nothing really big" (in which case, assuming the old wires were to code, etc. they are fine for a 50A feed into 100A (or larger!) subpanel) or do you mean "I want to put in a subpanel that can push out 100A of current to stuff at any given time - heater and welder and car charger and tools...." **Big difference**. More details will help.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel see my edits and pictures to answer your questions. Basically, for the 50A breakers, the wires are 4 AWG aluminum running exposed on the garage overhead. The wires are aluminum, not sure how bad that is but it does seem the wires are oversized, and have been used to feed the furnace without issues in the past.

Comment: @Edgar -- are the individual *wires* running exposed in the garage overhead, or is the *cable* running exposed in the garage overhead? Big difference!  Also, can you post a photo of your entire existing panel please?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The 100-amp subpanel is only because it seems that is what readily available at home improvement stores. I don't plan to do welding or service large water heaters with it, but maybe small, under-sink, on-demand water heater. And other regular use cases such as lighting and extra outdoor outlets.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The cables (sheathed wires or ROMEX?) are running exposed, not the individual wires. I'll add pictures of the whole panel

Comment: That is a good answer! 100A (and sometimes larger) are much more cost-effective than smaller panels because you have room to expand if you need it. So if you can stick to 50A then you're golden. But checking the limits...you **may** even be able to upsize the breaker a bit, but there are a bunch of factors relating to wire/cable type, connections, etc. so I'll leave that to the experts.

Comment: @Edgar -- can you get us photos of the printing/labeling on that cable with the 4AWG wires in it, even?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added a picture of the cable, the last letters to the right that got cut off says "CDRS"

Comment: @Edgar -- where are you trying to put this subpanel at, and can you give us more details about these bathroom heaters you're trying to feed?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The subpanel will be on the west interior wall of my garage, the main panel is on the east wall. There will be about 24 feet distance between the two panels. The subpanel will be on the wall where the two 50A cables run down before getting into the crawlspace and furnace. So, the placement will be for my installation convenience, but there will be the required 3 feet or so clearance and height access/visibility. 

Example tiny water heater: 2.5 gallon Bosch point-of-use water heater (home depot URL link is too long to paste here)

Comment: Is replacing the existing 4/2 SE cable an option?

Comment: Replacing the 4/2 SE cable is only an option if I feel confident enough to redo/rerun the wires. Otherwise, it is not an option if I cannot overcome my effort-conserving tendencies, especially trying to avoid overthinking it. EDIT: but please let me know what you think, especially if you see issues with keeping the 4/2 SE cable. I want to do things right, or not do it myself at all.

Comment: That piece of tape is not a legal blank cover. Just get a CH120 breaker and stick it there.  Eaton makes a flimsy blank cover that's hard to find, but it costs near as much as a breaker lol.

Comment: @Edgar -- also, can you get us a photo of the label on the inside left of your breaker box please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added pictures of the panel's inside left and right side.

Comment: @Edgar -- there also appears to be a label on the inside right, can you get me a closer shot of that label please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added a close up picture of the label in the panel's right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two 50A single breakers need to be handle-tied, or replaced with a 50A 2-pole breaker.  You can't have two singles on a 240V load like that.

The empty breaker space at bottom left should be filled with a proper UL-listed thing.  They make blank filler plates, but I find them flimsy and expensive.  I just use actual breakers, a CH120 is around $5.

> (1) reusing the existing (6 AWG aluminum) wires from the 30-amp circuit to service a new heat pump with a dedicated 25-amp replacement double-pole breaker

Yeah, that plan is fine.  Use "MAC Block connectors" to splice from the #6 aluminum to whatever other wires (Al or Cu) you'd continue with.

Note that since the #6 aluminum run does not have a neutral, they must be 240V-only heat pumps. Cannot use bare as a neutral.

You may find it challenging to land #6 wire on a 25A breaker.

> (2) reusing the wires from the two 50-amp circuit to service a 100-amp subpanel to serve future wiring projects

Waii--what???

OK, you see that dual 30A and you immediately get "This is a 30A 240V circuit".

But then you see those two 50A singles and for some reason you think that isn't the same exact thing.  *It is the same exact thing*, but somebody left off the mandatory handle tie so it looks weird.

So think of it as a 50A 2-pole breaker.

The problem is, the existing #4Al cable has only 3 wires and cannot supply a 120/240V subpanel.

- You need the bare wire for safety ground. This isn't 1963, you need a ground wire.
- Because it's #4 or larger, you **can** get neutral by re-marking one of the  black wires white with tape.
- That leaves you 1 wire left to use for "hot", and that means the far panel can only be 120V.

The good news is, the SE/XHHW cable is allowed 75C temperature, so it can be provisioned to 65A and use a 70A feed breaker.  There is no such thing as a 70A/1-pole breaker, so you will need to either re-use a 50A, or obtain a 70A/2-pole and use only one pole of it.